# Basic Asterisk Help

Tags: voip, asterisk

I'm very new to Asterisk but not Linux

I have followed some of the tutorials online but have been unsuccessful each time, this is what I want to achieve, but can you help me with what I need to put in the config files to do it?

I have a SIP account with a provider who gave me a phone number, I have the domain, username and pass for the account. I want asterisk to be able to be a client to this account to accept and make calls through.

I want two accounts/users for my softphones the main one 100 to receive all incoming calls from the public numberand make calls and the second account 200 just to make outgoing calls and calls to 100.

Its a simple setup, but I really don't know what to put in what config files.

Any help would be appreciated.

One last question, on top of this setup, would i be able to make it play a .wav audio file instead of going though to an extension, like a night mode or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a simple task to configure what you're asking for but there would be a good bit of config files to edit and review.

If you're open to it, something like Trixbox would be very easy to handle this, and you could spin it up in probably 20 minutes or so.

Overview:

```
1. Install Trixbox CE
2. Add Extensions Via GUI
3. PBX Settings -> Trunks
   a. Add new trunk
   b. In peer details add provider info
4. Inbound Route -> Add Inbound Route
   a. Add DID and route to Extension 100
5. Outbound Route -> PSTN -> Select your Trunk, add digit map.
```

You could add an IVR to play a wav recording, modify your inbound route to ring to a Time Condition, which would then toggle between extension 100 and the IVR.

You'd probably have much better luck going with something with a GUI, as it is meant to be super easy that way. If you don't like Trixbox, there's a few others, asterisk@home, Elastix, etc.